# How do I exclude jQuery as a dependency with Yarn?

Tags: jquery, npm, yarnpkg

In WordPress I'd rather not include jQuery as part of my build script, and instead load it explicitly in WP's enqueue functions in the header of the page.

However, I'm using Yarn + Gulp to autobundle together my vendor `package.json` dependencies into a single JS like so:

```
/**
 * compiles package.json dependencies into libraries.js
 */
gulp.task('yarn', function() {
    var filterJS = plugins.filter('**/*.js');
    currentTask = 'yarn';
    return gulp.src(mainYarnFiles({
        paths: {
            modulesFolder: 'node_modules',
            jsonFile: 'package.json'
        }
    }))
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({
            errorHandler: reportError
        }))
        .pipe(filterJS)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('libraries.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

So all the dependencies end up in `libraries.js`. The problem is that jQuery is a dependency of many of the dependencies in my `package.json`, and it always gets included in the `libraries.js`. I want to exclude it from being compiled.

This is my `package.json`'s dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dense": "https://github.com/gocom/dense",
    "fitvids.1.1.0": "^1.1.0",
    "slick-carousel": "1.7.1"
}
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: One thought I had was to remove the /jquery/ directory from node_modules before it gets compiled, or maybe add a resolution for jQuery in `package.json` that is a blank file?

Comment: If I understand correctly `mainYarnFiles()` returns an array of file names/paths that is then passed to `gulp.src()`. I'd test that by doing something like `var test = mainYarnFiles(...` then `console.log(test)`. If that assumption is true, you can simply remove the jquery entry from that array before passing it to gulp.src

Comment: You might also be able to do something like `plugins.filter(['**/*.js', '!**/jquery.js'])` if you know the exact name of the jquery file in question. Note the `!`, that means "not this file". I know that works in the .src array directly, might also work in the filter.